# Discord bot deployed on heroku crashes after launch

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, deployment, discord.py, python-asyncio

I made a chat bot for discord channel and if I run it from my local machine, it works well. When I am trying to deploy it on heroku, it doesn't appear online in discord and then it crashes.

I'm trying to find an explanation of the 'status 255' (see logs), but it just means 'mistake'?

After launch the bot makes one 'get' request (I tried to make my bot asynchronous and added one asyncio task) and I think the problem is with that.

```
def is_xur_here() -> bool:
    """Function checking Xur and returns True/False."""
    xur_url = 'https://paracausal.science/xur/current.json'

    response = requests.get(xur_url, headers=HEADERS)
    data = response.json()

    search_result = False if data is None else True

    return search_result
```

Also I have another bot deployed on heroku and it works well. I think the problem is with requests so I tried to make another Procfile (web), but heroku reports that it doesn't see any web process.

#### Procfile:

```
worker: python bot_main.py
```

#### Requirements.txt:

```
aiohttp==3.6.3
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==20.3.0
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
certifi==2020.11.8
chardet==3.0.4
discord==1.0.1
discord.py==1.5.1
fuzzywuzzy==0.18.0
idna==2.10
lxml==4.6.2
multidict==4.7.6
python-dotenv==0.15.0
python-Levenshtein==0.12.0
requests==2.25.0
soupsieve==2.0.1
urllib3==1.26.2
yarl==1.5.1
```

#### Logs from heroku:

```
2021-01-25T09:29:46.725997+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-01-25T09:29:50.461679+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python bot_main.py`
2021-01-25T09:29:51.062255+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-01-25T09:29:54.253986+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 255
```

Here is the [bot code](https://github.com/Interligo/discord-bot-for-destiny2) for convenience if someone wants to look it through. I really don't know what else may be nessessary to get the answer and I will be grateful for any direction.

Comment: Have you got a requirements file? - A necessary file for the dependency and imports heroku reads and imports upon launch

Comment: @Cohen, yes. I added the information from requrements. Thanks for your answer!